# Lazy Load Directives in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I could not really find an answer on SO about this, so if there exists a solution or even best practice about lazy loading of directives in Angular (RC4), I would be happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

lazy loading was introduced with rc.5 and is for loading modules. However, you can organize your directives in modules according your needs.

See https://angularjs.blogspot.de/ for directions how to get started with lazy loading.

> Lazy Loading In addition to enabling AoT compilation and generally
>   improving the developer experience of Angular2, NgModules enable a
>   simple way to lazy load pieces of your application via the router. A
>   simple example illustrates this:
>
> ```
> import {RouterModule} from
>  ‘@angular/router’ import {NgModule} from ‘@angular/core’ @NgModule({  
>  declarations: [ MyComponent, MyHomeRoute ],   bootstrap: [ MyComponent
>  ],   imports: [
>      RouterModule.forRoot([
>        { path: ‘home’, component: MyHomeRoute },
>        { path: ‘lazy’, loadChildren: ‘./my-lazy-module’ }
>      ]) }) class MyAppModule {}
> ```
>
> You simply define a `loadChildren` property on a route, and Angular
>   will go fetch the module at that location and load the routes defined
>   in it into the router config.